# How to get more decimal places on the output counting square root

Tags: c

and forgive me if I do anything wrong, I am the first-timer here and my English isn't the best. Also, I am beginner in C

We have school project in C, where we have to write function that counts square root. We cannot use math.h. I have made it to work, but there is problem with output which I dont know how to solve.

I am getting this: "my_sqrt = ?.??????.10e?" for example: "1.414214.10e1"

but i need to get this: "my_sqrt = ?.??????????.10e??"ex: "1.4142145678.10e+01"
How do I do it?

This is the code:

```
double fabs(double x) {     //just abs()
    if (x < 0)
        x = -x;
    return x;
}

double my_sqrt(double x) {   //sqrt function
    double y = 1;
    while(fabs(y*y - x) >= 0.00000000001)
        y = ((x/y) + y) / 2;
    k++;
    return y;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num;

    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &num);    // char to int

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)    // this will just print help
        getHelp();
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "--sqrt") == 0)    // this is for sqrt
        printf("my_sqrt = %f.10e%d", my_sqrt(num), k);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why the downvote? They are a new user, they've posted their attempt, it's not obvious to someone new to C.

Comment: Your code does not compile as it is know. (What is `k++` supposed to mean?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you meant to use `%.10f` (print a double with 10 decimal places) instead of `%f.10` (print a double with standard number of decimal places followed by the string `.10`) in your format string. For more details refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf.

Another problem with your code is this call:

```
printf("my_sqrt = %f.10e%d", my_sqrt(num), k);
```

Here you expect `my_sqrt(num)` to be evaluated first so that it can set `k`. But the order of evaluation of the arguments of a function call is unspecified. The program may first get the value of `k` (zero) and just then evaluate the sqrt call.

Comment: @JensGustedt, true. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, i want to add that we should encourage new comers. and coming to the answer of the question you asked... use %e to represent float in scientific format

Answer (score 0):

Use `"%.*e"` to get whatever number of decimal places after the `.` that you need along with exponential notation.

```
// printf("my_sqrt = %f.10e%d", my_sqrt(num), k);
// 10 digits after the decimal point
int Digs = 10;
printf("my_sqrt = %.*e %d\n", Digs, my_sqrt(num), k);
```